# Data extraction from cdata using expat in C

Tags: c, xml-parsing, cdata, expat-parser

I am able to parse XML successfully, but I am facing probelm while extracting data from `CDATA`. For this, I am using `XML_SetCdataSectionHandler(parser,CDATAstart,CDATAend)`. And by using this, my program can identify where the `cdata` exists but I am not able to get inside data from that `cdata`.I don't know how to code inside `CDATAstart` and `CDATAend` to extract the data. Can someone please help me in doing this. My xml parser is shown below

```
int parse_xml(char *buff, size_t buff_size) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sos.xml", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to open file\n");
            return 1;
    }
    XML_Parser parser = XML_ParserCreate(NULL);
    XML_SetElementHandler(parser, start_element, end_element);
    XML_SetCharacterDataHandler(parser, handle_data);
    XML_SetCdataSectionHandler(parser,CDATAstart,CDATAend);
    XML_SetCharacterDataHandler(parser, handle_data);
    memset(buff, 0, buff_size);
    printf("strlen(buff) before parsing: %d\n", strlen(buff));
    size_t file_size = 0;
    file_size = fread(buff, sizeof(char), buff_size, fp);  /* parse the xml */
    if (XML_Parse(parser, buff, strlen(buff), XML_TRUE) == XML_STATUS_ERROR)
    {
            printf("Error: %s\n", XML_ErrorString(XML_GetErrorCode(parser)));
    }
    fclose(fp);
    XML_ParserFree(parser);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CdataSectionHandler`s only tell you when a CDATA section starts and ends, the actual data is delivered through the `CharacterDataHandler` (or, if omitted, the `DefaultHandler`).